# Cannot view the dafault page for tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I installed apache tomcat and started the service on my server:

[root@RHEL-6 init.d]# ps -aux | grep -i tomcat
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
root     31281  3.0  1.2 3724272 99624 pts/0   Sl   06:08   0:03 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     31326  0.0  0.0 103240   836 pts/0    S+   06:10   0:00 grep -i tomcat

but i cannot access the page from my local machine.it says "Page Not Found"

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you put in the port number? Tomcat usually comes on port 8080 so try

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

You can find the port number in [tomcat folder]\conf\server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Yes i am trying just this way but just providing my server ip address in place of the "localhost"

Comment: Does localhost work if you're logged onto the server? Can you ping your server's ip address from your client computer?

Comment: Port 8080 might not be open on your server's firewall. You can change the port to 80 if you need to. Just change it in server.xml and restart tomcat. You then won't need to specify any port in the URL

Comment: yes both localhost works and i can ping the server ip from my machine

Comment: Thans a lot the port 8080 was closed.it is now opened and i can access the page, i have one more little doubt, i do not want my users to remember the ip address since it is combersome, can i access the page through my hostname

Comment: You should be able to if it's on an internal network. If you want to expose this to the web then you'll need to sign up for a domain name and link that to your server.